# How to use RAF in gaming applications on Roku?

Tags: ads, roku, brightscript

I wrote a simple game using roScreen, and I want to put RAF in there.

For example when character fails, I would like to show him few ads and then get back to game. I wrote a function that draws message and waits for 'OK' or 'instant_replay' key-press, and supposed to show standart ads here, but it doesn't. It simpy draws message.

```
function ExitOrResume(screen as object, compositor as object, msgport as object, PodIface as object) As boolean
adPods = podIface.getAds(msgport)
shouldPlayContent = podIface.showAds(adPods)
bm1 = CreateObject("roBitmap", "pkg:/images/exit.png")
reg1 = CreateObject("roRegion", bm1, 0, 0, 200, 200)
sprite1 = compositor.NewSprite(240, 240, reg1)
compositor.Draw()
screen.SwapBuffers()
sprite1.Remove()
while true
    msg = wait(0, msgport)
    if msg.getInt() = 6' codes.button_select_pressed
        return true
    else if msg.getInt() = 7 'codes.button_instant_replay_pressed
        return false
    end if
end while
end function
```

what am i doing wrong? maybe I simply do not understand what RAF is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `msgport` param when calling `getAds()` and that should do it:

```
adPods = podIface.getAds()
shouldPlayContent = podIface.showAds(adPods)
```

A few more things to keep in mind:

- `showAds()` is a blocking call, so as written, your msg will show only after the ad
- check the value of `shouldPlayContent` to determine if user exited the ad early with Back button and figure what to do then (e.g. show another ad? or tell them to watch another add for extra life? be nice, do not try to prevent exiting a single ad)
- keep in mind ad video would play behind your UI, so better clear `roScreen` first